# Java 7 application built with OSX 10.9 crashes on OSX 10.7.5

Tags: java, macos, java-7, osx-mavericks

I have built a Java 7 bundle for my application on OSX10.9, all appears well but when I try it on OSX 10.7 it crashes on startup, its been tried with both 10.7.3 and 10.7.5. Im sure an early access version of Java 7 did work but the current version fails every time.

But Java 7 is supported on OSX 10.7.3 and later, right ?

Details below:

```
Process:         launchd [229]
Path:            /Applications/Jaikoz.app/Contents/MacOS/Jaikoz
Identifier:      com.jthink.jaikoz
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [110]

Date/Time:       2013-10-30 21:10:32.986 +0000
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7.5 (11G56)
Report Version:  9

Interval Since Last Report:          9929716 sec
Crashes Since Last Report:           15
Per-App Crashes Since Last Report:   1
Anonymous UUID: 9162B9F6-4E51-4991-9437-5E6CB7C3A73D

Crashed Thread:  Unknown

Exception Type:  EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes: KERN_PROTECTION_FAILURE at 0x00007fff5fc01028

Backtrace not available

Unknown thread crashed with X86 Thread State (64-bit):
  rax: 0x0000000000000055  rbx: 0x0000000000000000  rcx: 0x0000000000000000  rdx: 0x0000000000000000
  rdi: 0x0000000000000000  rsi: 0x0000000000000000  rbp: 0x0000000000000000  rsp: 0x0000000000000000
   r8: 0x0000000000000000   r9: 0x0000000000000000  r10: 0x0000000000000000  r11: 0x0000000000000000
  r12: 0x0000000000000000  r13: 0x0000000000000000  r14: 0x0000000000000000  r15: 0x0000000000000000
  rip: 0x00007fff5fc01028  rfl: 0x0000000000010203  cr2: 0x00007fff5fc01028
Logical CPU: 0

Binary images description not available


External Modification Summary:
  Calls made by other processes targeting this process:
    task_for_pid: 2
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by this process:
    task_for_pid: 0
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0
  Calls made by all processes on this machine:
    task_for_pid: 312
    thread_create: 0
    thread_set_state: 0

Model: Macmini2,1, BootROM MM21.009A.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core 2 Duo, 1.83 GHz, 2 GB, SMC 1.19f2
Graphics: Intel GMA 950, GMA 950, Built-In, spdisplays_integrated_vram
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 1 GB, DDR2 SDRAM, 667 MHz, 0xAD00000000000000, 0x48594D503531325336344350382D59352020
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM1, 1 GB, DDR2 SDRAM, 667 MHz, 0xAD00000000000000, 0x48594D503531325336344350382D59352020
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x168C, 0x86), Atheros 5424: 2.1.14.9
Bluetooth: Version 4.0.8f17, 2 service, 18 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Network Service: Ethernet, Ethernet, en0
Serial ATA Device: Hitachi HTS541680J9SA00, 80.03 GB
Parallel ATA Device: MATSHITACD-RW  CW-8124
USB Device: Keyboard Hub, apple_vendor_id, 0x1006, 0xfd500000 / 2
USB Device: Apple Keyboard, apple_vendor_id, 0x0221, 0xfd520000 / 3
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller, apple_vendor_id, 0x8205, 0x7d100000 / 2
USB Device: IR Receiver, apple_vendor_id, 0x8240, 0x7d200000 / 3
USB Device: Microsoft Wireless Optical Mouse® 1.00, 0x045e (Microsoft Corporation), 0x00e1, 0x5d200000 / 2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the problem I use the modified Appbundler project https://bitbucket.org/infinitekind/appbundler/ and I forgot when I tried to build this on Mavericks it failed because it could not find the 10.7 sdk.

So I changed

```
<arg value="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
      /MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.7.sdk"/>
<arg value="-mmacosx-version-min=10.7"/>
```

to

```
<arg value="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
     /MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk"/>
<arg value="-mmacosx-version-min=10.8"/>
```

but I should have just changed the first line, and left the second line alone

```
<arg value="/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms
     /MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk"/>
<arg value="-mmacosx-version-min=10.7"/>
```

Building my application using this version of Appbundler it now works okay on 10.7, 10.8 and 10.9. This change has independently been committed to the InfiniteKind project.